# Question about language design (arrays and indexing)

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Hashtable x = new Hashtable();
        string[] y = new string[]{ "hello", "world" };

        x.Add("msg", y);

        //Console.WriteLine(x["msg"][0]); why error?
        Console.WriteLine(x["msg"].GetType()); //System.String[]
        Console.WriteLine(((string[]) x["msg"])[0]);
    }
}
```

**Why** i cant access array items like this

```
Console.WriteLine(x["msg"][0]);//Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'
```

if compiler knows that its an array of strings

```
Console.WriteLine(x["msg"].GetType());//System.String[]
```

and it forces me to use such an ugly syntax?

```
Console.WriteLine(((string[]) x["msg"])[0]);
```

Comment: You want to use a generic collection type instead, like `Dictionary<string, string[]>`

Comment: Because `x["msg"]` returns an `object`, not a `string`.

Comment: You say that the compiler knows that it is of type string, but `GetType` is a **runtime** call, not a **compile time** call. The *runtime* knows the type; the compiler does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your hashtable isn't a generic.  All it knows is that added values are of type `object`.

The runtime type of `x["msg"]` is `string[]`, but its compile-time type is `object`.

This is the [signature of the HashTable indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.item?view=netframework-4.8): `object this[object key] { get; set; }`.  In other words, at *compile time*, any object retrieved using the indexer will have compile-time type `object`.

You can use the generic `Dictionary<Tkey, TValue>` instead.  This will retain the compile-time type information:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
dict.Add("msg", new string[]{ "hello", "world" });
Console.WriteLine(dict["msg"][0]);
```

Comment: I also recently learned that Dictionary uses HashTable mechanics for matching too.

Comment: Typo: should be `dict`, not `x`.

Comment: @Sach Thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because `HashTable` doesn't know what the type of objects stored in it are. When you get something out of it (e.g. with your `x["msg"]`) the value of the data returned is going to be of type `object`. And since `object` doesn't know how to deal with the indexer operator, trying to force it will result in an error.

It doesn't matter what the underlying data is. What matters is the type of the variable itself is. HashTable returns `object`s, so without casting you can only do stuff to it what you could normally do with an `object` variable. This is the nature of using a statically-typed language like C#. (As opposed to a dynamically-typed language like Javascript.)

If, however, you used a generic collection like `Dictionary<string, string[]>`, you could do this easily. This is because `Dictionary` uses the generic type parameter to determine what the actual type of the data stored within it is, and so returns values of the correct type.

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> x = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
string[] y = new string[]{ "hello", "world" };

x.Add("msg", y);

Console.WriteLine(x["msg"][0]); // Will execute perfectly fine
```